# UWP CopyAsync of StorageFile is not working in release build, throws exception

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need to copy an icon file in C:// drive due to the first run of my UWP FullTrust Application. Here below is my code, which is working properly in Debug mode but not works in Release mode.

```
var packagePath = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var srcPath = Path.Combine(packagePath.Path, "Assets\\Systray_icon.ico");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(srcPath);

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\");
await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyAppFolder", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\MyAppFolder\\");

await storageFile.CopyAsync(sf);
```

**The folder has been created in both Debug and Release mode but due to copy throws an exception in release mode.**

> The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80070002)

Any kind of help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your issue. According to the error message, it might be related to the missing file. Could you please check if the file exists in **projectPath\bin\x86\Release\AppX\Assets**?

Comment: How about your progress? Has your issue been solved? If not, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Thanks man. The problem was in folder creation in release mode. I have posted a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. In release mode, folder creation was taking time sometimes as I didn't use Task in asynchronous await due to folder creation. So I'm posting workable code samples for others' help.

```
public void IconCopy()
{
   LOG(LogLevel.Standard, $"[IconCopy][+] ");
   try
   {
       var packagePath = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
       var srcPath = Path.Combine(packagePath.Path, "Assets\\Systray_icon.ico");
       Windows.Storage.StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(srcPath);

       await CreateContextMenuIconFolder();

       Windows.Storage.StorageFolder sf = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\MyAppFolder\\");
       await storageFile.CopyAsync(sf);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      LOG(LogLevel.Error, $"[IconCopy] Exception occured : {ex.Message.ToString()}");
   }

   LOG(LogLevel.Standard, $"[IconCopy][-] ");
}

public async Task CreateContextMenuIconFolder()
{
  LOG(LogLevel.Standard, $"[CreateContextMenuIconFolder][+] "); 

  try
  {
      Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\");
      await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyAppFolder", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     LOG(LogLevel.Error, $"[CreateContextMenuIconFolder] Exception occured : {ex.Message.ToString()}");
  }

  LOG(LogLevel.Standard, $"[CreateContextMenuIconFolder][-] ");
}
```